# mongodb: order and limit the collection, then order and limit the resulting document nested documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have the following data structure on my `game` collection:

```
{
    name: game1
    date: 2010-10-10
    media: [{
        id: 1,
        created: 2010-10-10 00:00:59
    }, {
        id: 2,
        created: 2010-10-10 00:00:30
    }]
},
{
    name: game2
    date: 2010-10-09
    media: [{
        id: 1,
        created: 2010-10-09 00:10:40
    }, {
        id: 2,
        created: 2010-10-09 09:01:00
    }]
}
```

I want to get the `game` with the highest date, then get the related `media` with the highest `created` to get it's id. In the example above, the result would be

```
{
    name: game1
    date: 2010-10-10
    media: [{
        id: 1,
        created: 2010-10-10 00:00:59
    }]
}
```

I tried to use the `find` and `find_one`, and also `aggregation`, but I could not figure a way to make this query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mongo newbie here, but seems like you could (a)use `find_one` to get the document with the highest date and (b)use [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to limit the fields returned to the highest `created`. If you've already figured out how to do (a) I'd add that query to the question.

Comment: How big will the media array grow? How often will values be appended?

Comment: There is a game document for each day, and media will be appended to it throughout the day.

But there might be the case where there are no media for the current day yet, so I need to get the latest one from the previous day.

Also, there might be other types of games later, so eventually I'll need to filter the games further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the `media` array in order to get the subdocument in that array where `created` is the highest then you [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) your documents by `date` and `created` all in descending order. Use [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) to output `n` documents which is `1` in our case.

```python
In [26]: import pymongo

In [27]: conn = pymongo.MongoClient()

In [28]: db = conn.test

In [29]: col = db.gamers

In [30]: list(col.aggregate([{"$unwind": "$media"}, {"$sort": {"date": -1, "media.created": -1}}, {"$limit": 1}]))
Out[30]: 
[{'_id': ObjectId('553323ec0acf450bc6b7438c'),
  'date': '2010-10-10',
  'media': {'created': '2010-10-10 00:00:59', 'id': 1},
  'name': 'game1'
}]
```

Comment: If I got it right, it "deconstructs" the games by each media, sorts them, and returns the first. Is this it?
I'm reading all the docs about the aggregation framework, I feel this time examples alone won't be enough :p

Comment: @MarcioCruz added explanation

Comment: Worked. Actually the question looks kinda silly after seeing the answer... There might be some performance questions and more queries as the project grows, but for now it is enough. Thanks!